# venv not sticking across subprocess.run on python/windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess, virtualenv

When I make a python venv on Windows:

```
C:\> mkdir C:\tvenv
C:\> cd C:\tvenv
C:\> python -m venv v
```

And then create these three files:

**t.bat**

```
   call "C:\tvenv\v\Scripts\activate.bat"
   python t1.py
```

**t1.py**

```
  import subprocess
  import sys
  print('T1', sys.executable)
  subprocess.run(['python', 't2.py'])
```

**t2.py**

```
  import sys
  print('T2', sys.executable)
```

And then I run `t.bat`:

```
C:\> t.bat
```

**OBSERVED OUTPUT**

```
T1 C:\tvenv\v\Scripts\python.exe
T2 C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
```

The following happens:

1. `t.bat` activates a venv and calls `t1.py`.
2. `t1.py` correctly reports the `sys.executable` from the venv
3. `t1.py` then calls `subprocess.run(['python', 't2.py'])`
4. **`t2.py` then reports the system-wide `sys.executable`, not the one from the `venv`**

ie I would have expected the output to be:

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
T1 C:\tvenv\v\Scripts\python.exe
T2 C:\tvenv\v\Scripts\python.exe
```

as `activate.bat` sets:

```
  set PATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts;%PATH%
```

It puts the venv Scripts dir at the front of the PATH.

so why doesn't `subprocess.run(['python'])` find the venv python instead of the system-wide one?

**Update**

I am on latest Windows 10 x64. I just completely reinstalled Python 3.9.1 from the standard python.org Windows installer, and didn't even put it in my `PATH`.  Problem is still present.

Comment: `subprocess.run()`  launches in a new, default environment and doesn't share the environment of the launching process.

Comment: @Grismar: That's not correct, the default behaviour is to inherit parents environment.  I printed out `os.environ['PATH']` in both t1.py and t2.py, and they both show the `venv` `PATH` present correctly.  The default behaviour of `subprocess.run` is to inherit the parents environment: *If env is not None, it must be a mapping that defines the environment variables for the new process; these are used instead of the default behavior of inheriting the current process’ environment.*

Comment: This is probably some manifestation of Windows idiocy. Which precise Windows version are you on, and what's your Python version? How was it installed?

Comment: @tripleee: I am on latest Windows 10 x64.  I just completely reinstalled Python 3.9.1 from the standard python.org windows installer, and didn't even put it in my PATH.  Problem reoccurs.  This is a weird one, can anyone reproduce on their Windows machine?

Comment: For the record, no repro on MacOS with Python 3.7.2 by way of `pyenv` via Homebrew.

Comment: @tripleee: Yeah I think its a Windows-specific issue.  Anyone try to repro on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is indeed linked to Windows behavior and in fact the main solution is to use `sys.exectuable` instead of `python` to actually launch the expected python binary instead of letting the OS resolving that by himself.
Much more explanations on the issue and how OS are impacting the behavior of `subprocess.run` command: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/86207